# How to create a virtual pdf file to be used in Django unit tests

Tags: python, django, file, unit-testing, pdf

I have this function in my viewset to upload a pdf file to A

```
@api_view(['POST', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def upload_file_pdf(request):

    # Uploading and saving the file if the request is a POST - Validating the extension of the file as well
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            upload = Upload(file_pdf=request.FILES["filepond"])
            upload.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        upload.save()
        return Response(upload.pk, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Deleting the file if the request is DELETE
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        file_pk = str(json.loads(request.body))
        return Response(file_pk, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I want to test it, I don`t know how to create a sample pdf file in unit tests

```
  def test_create(self):

        self.pdf_file = ....

        self.client.post('/api/v1/file/pdf/', data={"filepond": self.pdf_file})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

What should I put in front of self.pdf_file

Comment: You can use one of the [io's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module classes (perhaps BinaryIO) to emulate in-memory file.

Comment: @Charnel Would you please provide more details ? I am junior :) 
The link is so useful by the way, I`m reading it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: simulate writing to a file object without creating a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718938/python-simulate-writing-to-a-file-object-without-creating-a-file)

Comment: FYI PDFManager comes from PyPDF2

Comment: I used this:
self.pdf_file = open("myfile.pdf", "rb")
It came up with this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfile.pdf'

Comment: @Edeki Okoh 
I put this :

'
        merger = PdfFileMerger()

        self.pdf_file = merger.write('result.pdf')  # This creates a file. I want to avoid this
        merger.close()

'

I received this error:

django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filepond'

Comment: I think I am creating the pdf correctly but this is another error coming up, unrelated to pdf creation.

django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filepond'